# How do you get from this to this formula?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

I have the formula :
$$3×4^{n-1}×1×\left({1\over 3}\right)^{n-1}$$
And I would like to know how to get to this one ([which is equal](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3%20%C3%97%204%5E%28n-1%29%20%C3%97%201%2a%281/3%29%5E%28n-1%29%20=%203%2a%284/3%29%5E%28n-1%29%20)) :
$$3× \left({4\over 3}\right)^{n-1}$$
How can I do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well first you can rewrite

$(3)$ x $(4^{n-1})$ x $1$ x $({{1}\over {3}})^{n-1}$ as

$(3)$ x $(4^{n-1})$ x $({{1}\over {3}})^{n-1}$.

Then using the identity that $a^nb^n = (ab)^{n}$ we get

$(3)$ x $({{4}\over {3}})^{n-1}$

which is the answer you wanted.

Comment: Thank you for your answer !

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Use the fact that $a^nb^n = (ab)^n$. Put $a = 4,\;b = \frac 13$.

Comment: I'm gonna try this thanks !

Comment: I found it by myself thanks to you !